# How to create list of dictionaries from list of items in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

I'd like to convert a list of items into a list of dictionaries. See below for my example.

```
list_of_items = ['a','b','c','d']


desired_result = [{'name':'a'},{'name':'b'},{'name':'c'},{'name':'d'}]
```

My attempt:

```
function myAttempt(list_of_items){
   list_of_items.forEach(function (i) {
  return {'name':i};
 });
  return list_of_items
};

myAttempt(list_of_items)
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have dictionaries. It has, in your case, arrays and objects, and you're looking to turn your array into an array of objects.

Comment: too easy with `Array.prototype.map()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` method to return array of objects.

```js
var list_of_items = ['a','b','c','d']
var result = list_of_items.map(function(e) {
  return {name: e}
})

console.log(result)
```

Or if you can use ES6 arrow functions you can get same result like this.

```
var result = list_of_items.map(e => ({name: e}))
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways how to do it. You can pass various arrays into the function, same with the `key`. May be `name` or whatever you like.

```js
let list_of_items = ['a','b','c','d'],
    result = [];

function myAttempt(arr, key){
  arr.forEach(function(v){
    let obj = {};
    obj[key] = v;
    result.push(obj);
  });
  console.log(result);
}

myAttempt(list_of_items, 'name');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this answer is duplicate with @Kinduser's answer, but it looks shorter:

```js
var list_of_items = ['a','b','c','d'];

list_of_items.forEach(function(element, index, list) { 
  list[index] = {'name': element}; 
});

console.log(list_of_items);
```